# D3.js maps: change the color of the paths one after another

Tags: animation, d3.js, maps

I have made a map with `d3.js`and now I would like to color several countries one after another:

- at 1 seconde, I would like Spain to be in lets say red color,
- at 1.5 sec, France should be red (Spain should remain red)
- at 2 sec, Germany should be red (Spain and France should remain red)
- and so on

So far I could change the color of all the countries at once. I try to do what I want with a try `.transition().delay(500)` but it didn't work.

This is my code so far:

```html
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.2/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var w = 1000;
    var h = 550;

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

    var path = d3.geoPath()
        .projection(d3.geoMercator()
        //.scale(0) 
        //.translate([200, 2100])
        );

    var countries_visited= ['Spain','France','Germany','Poland', 'Finland'] 
    d3.json(
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johan/world.geo.json/master/countries.geo.json",
        function (error, json) {

            //draw svg lines of the boundries
            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "black")
                .selectAll("path")
                .data(json.features)
                .enter()
                .append("path")
                .attr("d", path)
                .attr('fill', '#e7d8ad');;

            d3.timeout(function() { 
                d3.selectAll('path')
                //.transition().delay(500)  //should color countries, one after the other
                .attr('fill', colorCountry);
            }, 500);
        }
    );

    function colorCountry(country){
        if (countries_visited.includes(country.properties.name)) {
            return '#c8b98d';
        } else {  // why do I need a else (otherwise set to black
            return '#e7d8ad';
        };

    };
</script>
</body>
```

As a side question: why do I need a else statement in `colorCountry`? Why the country `fill` changes if I don't add the `else`?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I added a link to the json. I get it that the fill is set back to default bu why my function `colorCountry` "removed" the fill that was set when I added the path? Why the fill isn't "remembered"?

Comment: Because the function will then return undefined for countries not part of the list, and this is thus undefined and not the initial color which will be applied

Comment: Ok, I get it! Thanks for that! No other way around than having a else statement?

Comment: I don't see a viable simple alternative in this case.

Comment: OK I will keep it then!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not to diminish from Xavier's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49343085/7106086), you can also avoid a loop with a more d3 idiomatic method by setting the delay with a function (rather than with an increment):

```
d3.selectAll("path")
  .filter(function(d) { return countries_visited.indexOf(d.properties.name) > -1 })
  .transition()
  .delay(function(d) { return countries_visited.indexOf(d.properties.name) * 500 + 1000; })
  .attr("fill","#c8b98d");
```

This looks like:

```html
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.2/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>

  var w = 1000;
  var h = 550;

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", w).attr("height", h);

  var path = d3.geoPath().projection(d3.geoMercator());

  var countries_visited = ['Spain','France','Germany','Poland', 'Finland'];

  d3.json(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johan/world.geo.json/master/countries.geo.json",
    function (error, json) {

      svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "black")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(json.features)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("id", function(d) { return d.properties.name; })
        .attr("d", path)
        .attr('fill', '#e7d8ad');

        d3.selectAll("path")
          .filter(function(d) { return countries_visited.indexOf(d.properties.name) > -1 })
          .transition()
          .delay(function(d) { return countries_visited.indexOf(d.properties.name) * 500 + 1000; })
          .attr("fill","#c8b98d");

 
  });

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: That's a funny shade of red!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a slightly modified version of your code which displays visited countries one after the other:

```html
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.2/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>

  var w = 1000;
  var h = 550;

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", w).attr("height", h);

  var path = d3.geoPath().projection(d3.geoMercator());

  var countries_visited = ['Spain','France','Germany','Poland', 'Finland'];

  d3.json(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/johan/world.geo.json/master/countries.geo.json",
    function (error, json) {

      svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "black")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(json.features)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("id", function(d) { return d.properties.name; })
        .attr("d", path)
        .attr('fill', '#e7d8ad');

      var delay = 1000;

      countries_visited.forEach( country => {
        d3.selectAll('#' + country)
          .transition().delay(delay)
          .attr('fill', '#c8b98d');
        delay += 500;
      });
    }
  );

</script>
</body>
```

It consists in creating several independent transitions. One for each visited country:

```
var delay = 1000;

countries_visited.forEach( country => {
  d3.selectAll('#' + country)
    .transition().delay(delay)
    .attr('fill', '#c8b98d');
  delay += 500;
});
```

Each transition is given a delay, which retards the moment the country is colored. And it's the creation of transitions itself that increments the delay to apply for the next country.

I included an `id` for each path (country) in order to easily select it during the transition and apply the new color. This is a way to answer your side question, by only selecting the element to modify, we can just modify the `fill` attribute of the modified country.

Comment: Merci beaucoup !